# How to use oledbconnection in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to the vb and I want to create project where if I click this button, form 2 will show and the information from it will change depends on what room button I click. i know how to connect a database but I am so clueless on how to make it that way, please help me. Thank you everyone

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\arima\Documents\Consumer & rooms Database.mdb")
```

Yup, Stuck

Comment: [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71503281/832052) a question today which has your answer

Answer (score 0):

You also need an `OleDbCommand` associated with the connection. The `OleDbCommand.CommandText` property is where your SQL statements go. Then you can `.Open()` the connection, so the command object can execute the SQL statements.

Here's the general idea:

```
Using con As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = ?", con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 25).Value = "SomeValue"
    con.Open()
    Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While rdr.Read()
            ' Do something with each record
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```

Alternatively, you can use an `OleDbDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable` or `DataSet`:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Using con As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
      da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = ?", con)

    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 25).Value = "SomeValue"
    da.Fill(dt)
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Another question, what is the oledbdataadapter for? How to use it? Sorry i am still pretty new at using database in vb.net

Comment: DataAdapter is for disconnected data use: run a query to download all the data, and then use it with the connection closed (and destroyed). Can be simpler, but it's higher memory use and can't do anything until the LAST record is retreived. DbDataCommand/DataReader lets you stream data one record at a time over and active connection. Can be more complex, but you can start using data as soon as the FIRST record is ready, and it can be so much more memory efficient if you're careful.